# Does distributing compiled code with "no reverse engineering" notice amount to pre-patent publication?

Tags: patents

If I made an invention of a patentable computer algorithm, and then implemented it, *compiled* and published a program online, while retaining the copyright notice like "reverse engineering is strictly prohibited" (which makes it protected from reverse engineering by law, at least European law afaik), would it amount to a pre-patent publication of the invention? Technically if nobody is legally allowed to study the program, they wouldn't have the means to derive at the invention? Of course they could study it "quietly" and possibly come up with their own algorithm, but my question is about whether the patent court would say that I've published it which makes it impossible for me to patent it (I do know about a 6-month post-publication period that still allows me to patent in some jurisdictions).

As a follow-up question, would the same case of pre-patent publication of compiled code help me to claim the prior art if somebody else then went on to patent it themselves?

Comment: Is it a copyright or a patent issue? They are mutually exclusive.

Comment: @MindwinRememberMonica patent, i only said "copyright notice" as a place where i would say "reverse engineering prohibited" to indicate that the code is proprietary.

Comment: @Mindwin If there is a document that would be prior art if published, then it is under copyright. Only the patent itself is not copyrightable once you have the patent.

Comment: I understand cross posting is discouraged but if put on SE Ask Patents you might increase the chance of getting a response from an expert by in European patent law.

Comment: @GeorgeWhite oh wow didn't know there's one thanks for the tip!

Comment: In the US/Canada, reverse engineering is generally legal.  So the basis of the question is a bit problematic.

Comment: @PeterM so what if reverse engineering is legal in one country that means it is public disclosure everywhere in the world..?

Comment: @Harvey It means that if you publish the program on the internet, then people in the US and Canada have the right to reverse engineer it.  And if they follow a [clean room](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clean_room_design) process they may avoid any copyright issues, but that doesn't protect them from circumventing any patent protections.  However, software patents themselves are full of all sorts of complications in the first place, so that Ask Patents SE would be good place to be asking.

Comment: @PeterM this is what I don't get, whether compiled code is public disclosure or not. your comment says that in some countries it's not public because access is legally restricted whereas in other countries like the US it is very much public, therefore what, it's to be considered public everywhere in the world? aka it's weird that patents are local but art is global. it's not a question about a patent itself but how to reconcile those 2 aspects. thing is I really need to make use of the invention now to afford the patent in the first place, so I'm wondering if the fact that I compiled it helps

Comment: @Harvey I don't know the answer to your question, I was really just pointing out that there were assumptions in your questions.  But i'd argue that art is also local, as copyright laws are only based on local laws.  There is no global government that implements copyright laws, there are only treaties between countries that respect the copyright laws of other countries.  EG as per [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Non-US_copyrights) it states that " Eritrea, Ethiopia, Iran and Iraq have no copyright relations with the US"

Answer (score 4):

This supposes that the patentable concept can’t be learned form the operation of the whole program and hiding the invention while making use of the invention in public is not a disclosure.

However, in the US there is a famous case

> In re Blaisdell, 242 F.2d 779, 783, 113 USPQ 289, 292 (CCPA 1957); Hall v. Macneale, 107 U.S. 90, 96-97 (1882); Ex parte Kuklo, 25 USPQ2d 1387, 1390 (Bd. Pat. App. & Inter. 1992)

that concluded a public demonstration that didn’t expose the inner workings did start the clock on a bar to patentability. See previous question https://patents.stackexchange.com/questions/20886/would-the-demonstration-of-an-invention-be-considered-public-disclosure

The answer (from me) has the caveat that this is a pre-AIA case and courts might come to a different answer under that current law.

The U.S. has viewed public use, especially commercial public use, as disqualifying (after a grace period) but the rest of the world puts its emphasis on actual disclosure of the inventive concept so this result might be different elsewhere.

One thought experiment would be to analogize with an article in a widely available journal with the words Don’t read the article that starts on page 19 on the cover. From a disclosure point of view I do not think that is different from it being possible, but illegal, to read.

Comment: I witnessed a case with several excellent software developers involved. Someone said he had just read that Sun Microsystems had received a patent for XYZ. Someone said "but this can't be done... wait a second..." Within a few minutes three people had figured out how to do XYZ just from the knowledge that it was possible. When everyone believed it was impossible.

Answer (score 1):

I don’t think anyone anticipated that the “prior art” could have been created by illegal means. Something simpler, you printed a description of your invention and locked it into a safe. I crack the safe and publish that description.

IF this counts as prior art (a big if), and you can’t get the patent, and you lose money due to my illegal actions, then you can sue me for the damages.